# How do i create a wallet from a smart contract in Solidity?

Tags: wallets

Is there a way to create a wallet from a smart contract in Solidity ? If there is how can i do it ?
For example i want to create a smart contract that on deploy creates a new wallet and saves its address into an array.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That is no possible. I guess because generating the privateKey is costly. 
But you can generate first a wallet localy with web3 and then with solidity deploy a smart contract that get the address of the wallet as Owner and that contract has a method to transfer ether or token and that method can only triggered by Owner.